# Laravel View::share() does not work when testing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 project I've bound the current user to the views using the `share()` method like so:

```
View::share(['currentUser' => Sentry::getUser()]);
```

This works when browsing the site, all the views have access to the variable `$currentUser`. However, when attempting to test my application, the variable is never bound, despite a user definitely being logged in.

```
class PagesControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // This works, as halting the application and dumping the user manually demonstrate it as such.
        Sentry::login(User::first());
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->get('/');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

However, this simply results in a stack-trace of errors...

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: ~/Sites/laravel/app/views/layouts/application.blade.php) (View: ~/Sites/laravel/app/views/layouts/application.blade.php)

...

Caused by
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: ~/Sites/laravel/app/views/layouts/application.blade.php)

...

Caused by
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

The exact line this fails at is where the view tries to access the `$currentUser` variable.

If I use a view composer instead, like follows, it solves the problem in this instance - but I want the variable available in ALL views, not just the ones I specify, and I'd also like to know WHY this is occurring.

```
View::composer('layouts.application', function($view)
{
    $view->with('currentUser', Sentry::currentUser());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are doing `View::share` in app/start/global.php. This file is invoked by calling `parent::setUp()`, which is before you've done `Sentry::login`, and thus, `$currentUser` will be null. You should either find a way to delay the `View::share` (using a view composer is one way to do this) or just use `Sentry::getUser()` in your views.